# Why is the logistic regression implementation in Python incorrect?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have implemented logistic regression in Python. I think there is some bug in the code. I am not able to get the correct accuracy for the testset.
Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from math import *
import os, sys


class LogisticRegressionModel:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.theta = np.zeros((n+1, 1))
        print(self.theta)


    def SGD(self, trainingSet, epochs, minibatchsize, eta):
        m = len(trainingSet)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            derSum = np.zeros(self.theta.shape)
            for xi, yi in trainingSet:
                xi = np.concatenate(([[1]], xi), axis=0)
                #print(xi)
                hi = self.sigmoid(np.dot(np.transpose(self.theta), xi))
                derSum = derSum + (hi-yi)*xi

            self.theta = self.theta - eta/m*derSum

            print(self.cost(trainingSet))


    def cost(self, dataset):
        totCost=0
        for xi, yi in dataset:
            xi = np.concatenate(([[1]], xi), axis=0)
            hi = self.sigmoid(np.dot(np.transpose(self.theta), xi))
            totCost += -1*(yi*log(hi)+(1-yi)*log(1-hi))

        return totCost/len(dataset)



    def sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-1*z))


    def evaluate(self, testSet):
        mtest = len(testSet)
        count=0
        for xi, yi in testSet:
            xi = np.concatenate(([[1]], xi), axis=0)
            hi = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.theta.transpose(), xi))
            #print(str(hi[0, 0])+" "+str(yi))
            if hi>=0.5:
                hi=1
            else:
                hi=0
            if yi==hi:
                count+=1
        print(count/mtest*100)
```

The LR is a two-class classifier. The data set is having a linear decision boundary and I tested it using Octave which is giving an accuracy of more that 95%. But the above implementation stucks around 60%. I also tried changing the learning rate and other things. But that doesn't help.

Comment: In the `sigmoid` method you are using `math.exp`. Are you 100% sure that you didn't mean to use `numpy.exp`? Same with `log`. BTW: `sigmoid` doesn't depend on `self` hence it should either be a `staticmethod` or a simple function outside that class...  Other than thisI don't think I can help you.

Comment: ya since it is a binary classifer the output hypothesis is a real number..ANyways, I changed it up in the question and also  I tried np.exp but it still didn;t work..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for but when I had a similar problem, it turned out I was passing large values to the `sigmoid` function. Sigmoid of any value larger than `36`, I think, is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your training data is a list containing pairs like `([feature1,...,featuren], label)`, the following code seems to work fine for me. It's a modification of your code, except that I put things in array form where it was appropriate:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def log_loss(y,ypred):
    return -(y*np.log(ypred) + (1-y)*np.log(1-ypred)).mean()

class LogisticRegressionModel:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.theta = np.zeros((1,n+1))
        print(self.theta)


    def SGD(self, trainingSet, epochs, minibatchsize, eta):
        m = len(trainingSet)
        X = np.ones((self.n+1,m))
        Y = np.zeros((1,m))

        for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(trainingSet):
            X[1:,i] = xi
            Y[:,i] = yi

        for epoch in xrange(epochs):
            H = sigmoid(self.theta.dot(X))
            derSum = (H-Y).dot(X.T)

            self.theta -= eta * derSum/m

            print(log_loss(Y,H))


    def evaluate(self, testSet):
        mtest = len(testSet)
        X = np.ones((self.n+1,mtest))
        Y = np.zeros((1,mtest))
        for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(testSet):
            X[1:,i] = xi
            Y[:,i] = yi

        H = sigmoid(self.theta.dot(X))
        H = (H >= 0.5)
        print((H == Y).mean() * 100)
```

I'm not sure what's broken in your code, since this should work identically to yours (save for places where reloading the data is redundant).